# GNU parallel with variable format printf

Tags: awk, printf, gnu-parallel

I have a bit of issue getting the correct output format with the code below. The output should look like this:

```
bb.pdf---------------color found
HIGHLY Rate.pdf------color found
```

etc...etc

I am getting:

```
bb.pdf---------------color found
HIGHLY Rate.pdf---------------color found
```

OK, so I am trying the get variable printf formatting with the use of the `printf %s%*.*s%s` format
where the `*.*` is set dynamically at run time. In the code below, in the line that begins with `printf`, if I set;

```
printf "%s%0.55s%s" $file_name $pad; gs -o - -sDEVICE............etc etc etc
```

then the code runs. That tells me I am close in getting this to work. The problem is I cannot get
the `0` and the `$var_format` to send their values to `*.*`, which will give me the variable nature of `printf`, i.e. `printf "%s%0.$var_format%s"`. Appreciate anyone with an input.

A. Das

```
cat /cygdrive/i/PDF/$machine/results.csv | \
parallel -j200% --progress 'padlength=130;\
width=`echo {}| wc -c`;\
pad=$(printf '%0.1s' "-"{1..60});\
file_name=`echo -n {} | sed "s;.*/;;"`;\
var_format=$((padlength - width - 11 ));\
printf "%s%*.*s%s" $file_name 0 $var_format  $pad ;gs -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov {} 2>/dev/null | \
awk "/CMYK OK$/ {if (\$1>0 || \$2>0 || \$3>0) {print \"------------------------------\
color found\"; exit;} } \
END {print \"\"  }";' >> /cygdrive/i/PDF/$machine/color_report_summary.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Exmple on how to use `printf` with `awk`

```
cat file
bb.pdf
HIGHLY Rate.pdf
```

```
awk '{printf "%-30s %s\n", $0,var}' var="color found" file
bb.pdf                         color found
HIGHLY Rate.pdf                color found
```

`-30` tells that first filed have a space of `30` characters and is left adjusted.
You need to set sufficient space for the longest field one.

Comment: Gracias, I hate to set a fix field, also if you notice, awk is not acting on the file I want to printf. Awk is acting on the output of the gs command, so I cannot printf everything from awk.